# Problem with getUserMedia in EDGE version 99

Tags: javascript, webrtc, microsoft-edge, device

I have a problem. 
I need to capture the user's image, however in EDGE the image capture does not work.

Below is an example that works very well in Google Chrome

This (https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera) work in Chrome, but not work in EDGE.

This is message displayed EDGE console: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source in EDGE, version 99.0.1150.46, 64 bits`

```js
// Older browsers might not implement mediaDevices at all, so we set an empty object first
if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices = {};
}

// Some browsers partially implement mediaDevices. We can't just assign an object
// with getUserMedia as it would overwrite existing properties.
// Here, we will just add the getUserMedia property if it's missing.
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraints) {

    // First get ahold of the legacy getUserMedia, if present
    var getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    // Some browsers just don't implement it - return a rejected promise with an error
    // to keep a consistent interface
    if (!getUserMedia) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
    }

    // Otherwise, wrap the call to the old navigator.getUserMedia with a Promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
    });
  }
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: !true,
    video: true
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    // Older browsers may not have srcObject
    if ("srcObject" in video) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    } else {
      // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      video.play();
    };
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
  });
```

```html
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Comment: Have you allowed the camera permission for the site in Edge? Is there any other process using the video camera at the same time when you test in Edge? You need to make sure the webcam is not being used by another application. You can kill all applications that have used your camera recently to try to free any process lock and test again.

Comment: Yes, all permissions. Thanks, I will try this solution.

Comment: Hi, is there any update about the issue? Is the solution helpful to deal with the issue?

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, but nothing worked. The solution, which I don't think is the best, is to indicate the use of Chrome.

Comment: It's strange that it works in Chrome but not in Edge. They're both based on chromium. I suggest that you can also provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. Edge team will check the feedbacks and improve the product continuously.